# String to PDF with header and footer

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

What is the best and fastest way to:

1. Convert an HTML formatted string to multi-page PDF
2. Apply CSS to HTML elements in the string/PDF
3. Apply header and footer
4. Automatically pagenumber the PDF with a table of contents

Willing to purchase something for this but would rather have a quick/dirty method to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having good success with DOMPDF (http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/), supports loads of CSS (except float) and does repeated headers and footers nicely. You'd have to write your own TOC functionality, I think though. But it integrates really well with the rest of the Zend Framework app I'm building and I can recommend it.